# how to pass cookies to another Savon client

Tags: ruby, cookies, savon

I have two savon clients, where the second needs the cookies of the first, like an authentication cookie.
I have something like this, but the call of the second client fails with an error 302, probably because the cookie is not correct or not set...

```
client1 = Savon.client(
    wsdl: "https://example.com/Service1.asmx?WSDL"
)
response1 = client1.call(:authenticate_user, :login => login, :passwd => password)
response1_cookies = response1.http.cookies

client2 = Savon.client(
    wsdl: "https://example.com/Service2.asmx?WSDL"
)
response2 = client2.call(:get_user_info, cookies: response1_cookies)
```

any idea how I should get this working?

- savon gem version 2.6.0
- httpi gem version 2.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the 302 error I got was a server-side problem. The owner of the server had to reconfigure it, so nothing was wrong with my script... Happily ever after...